# I need to make a JavaScript function that will return DOM elements given a CSS selector w/o jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

JavaScript I have so Far

```
 var $= function(selector){
 var elements = [];
if (selector == "#some_id"){
  elements.push( document.getElementById("some_id"));
}else if (selector == '.some_class'){
  elements= document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");
} else if (selector == "div"){
  elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
}else if (selector == "img"){
  elements.push(document.getElementsByTagName("img"));
}
console.log(elements);
return elements;
};
```

Having a problem getting nested selectors like : ("img.some_class") and ("div.some_class#some_id")

Comment: See if this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, there are countless solutions out they're for this?

Comment: read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: You really need to explain why you can't use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) which works all the way back to IE8?  If you want compatibility before that, then get the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) library.  There really is no reason to reinvent this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`?

Here are two simple examples:

```
var el = document.querySelector(".myclass");
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div.note, div.alert");
```

See here for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll

A very simple simulation of jQuery selector:

```
$ = function (selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you were asked not to use neither JQuery nor **querySelector()/ querySelectorAll()**, like me.

You can find the nested selectors like this:

```
...} else if (selector == "div#some_id.some_class") {
  elements.push(document.getElementById("some_id"));
} else if (selector == "div.some_class#some_id") {
  elements.push(document.getElementById("some_id"));
} 
...
```

Your answer is kind of great, because I spent two days trying to get it and yours is just so simple, I could complete the last two tests really quickly.

I still have no clue why this even works in the first place, and it's so NOT dry, but I guess it'll be useful for people in the future.